# Is there a way to replace a postgresql array with a new array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried updating an array like I would other values ex:

```
update table set column = {'thing one','thing two'} where ...;
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
```

I'm really new to PostgreSQL, but I couldn't find any info on how to simply replace an entire array with a new array.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT

Answer (score 0):

I got it! the array has to be surrounded by single quotes, and no quotes can be inside the array!

```
update table set column = '{thing one, thing two}' where...;
```

Since I was eventually trying to do this in Node.js, the method would go like this:

```
set column = '{${req.get("attribute")}}' //with quotes and brackets around the attribute you want to update!
```